# Compare records and Generate records

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

My requirement is to arrange the records in chronological order and compare every record to its very next record in sequence. If the 2nd record is different than the previous record (in the asc order) pertaining to any field and the record is Active (i.e.flag = 'F'), then split the 2nd record by generating a record with eff_date = eff_dt of the second record - 1 day. If the next record is Inactive (ie.e flag = 'C' then only output this record but no need to split and create new record
Continue this comparison for all the records.

For e.g.,

```
product | eff_dt | store | region | type
12345 | 18/05/2017 | HA | CA | F
12345 | 05/10/2018 | K1 | CA | F
12345 | 01/02/2019 | K1 | CA | F
12345 | 15/07/2019 | AB | GA | C
12345 | 07/09/2019 | BT | MD | F
```

From the above table, first we arrange the records in chronological order.
Now we compare the first record with second record and see that "store" has changed in the second record `HA -> K1` and second record is active (flag = F). Hence, both the first record and the second record are needed for the output and the second record will be split in 2 parts - a new record is created with ( `eff_dt - 1` ) day.
Now when we compare the third record to the second record, we see that there is no change in the values of any field and also that the record is Active, and hence this record will be ignored and won't be output.
Now we compare the fourth record to the third record we see that it is Inactive (`flag = 'C'`) hence, this record will be output as-is but no new record will be generated like we did for the first scenario.
Finally, the 5th record is found to be the first **Active** record after the product was **closed** (in the 4th record), hence will be also output but no new record will be created.

The expected output will be :

```
product | eff_dt | store | region | type
12345 | 18/05/2017 | HA | CA | F      <<--- output
12345 | 04/10/2017 | HA | CA | F      <<--- new record generated with (eff_dt - 1)
12345 | 05/10/2018 | K1 | CA | F      <<--- output as-is
                                           <<--- record not output since no change in values
12345 | 15/07/2019 | AB | GA | C      <<--- record has changes but also Inactive. Hence, output as-is and new record generation not required
12345 | 07/09/2019 | BT | MD | F      <<--- record output since this indicates product is reopened and is active again. No new record required.
```

Can anyone please help with the above logic and how to split the record by creating a new record with eff_dt - 1.
Please let me know if additional information/clarification is necessary

Comment: You have six values in each row but only five column headers.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I interpret this as gap and islands problem with some twists.  Instead of putting the "end" values on different rows, I would put effective and end dates on one row:

```
select product, store, region, type,
       min(eff_dt),
       date_add(lead(eff_dt) over (partition by product order by min(eff_dt), -1) as
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by eff_dt) as seqnum_p,
             row_number() over (partition by product, store, region, type order by eff_dt) as seqnum_psrt
      from t
     ) t
group by product, store, region, type, (seqnum - seqnum_psrt);
```

If you want this on different rows, you can use `union all`:

```
select product, store, region, type, eff_dt
from (select t.*,
             lag(eff_dt) over (partition by product, store, region, type order by eff_dt) as prev_psrt_date,
             lag(eff_dt) over (partition by product order by eff_dt) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_date is null or prev_date <> prev_psrt_date
union all
select product, store, region, type,
       date_add(next_date, 1)
from (select t.*,
             lead(eff_dt) over (partition by product, store, region, type order by eff_dt) as next_psrt_date,
             lead(eff_dt) over (partition by product order by eff_dt) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_date <> next_psrt_date or next_psrt_date is null;
```

The trick here to find rows with the same values is to compare the previous/next date -- but by different partitions of the data.  This is simpler than comparing each column independently, and it also works for `NULL` values.

Comment: @marie20 . . . The first does not.  The second should.

Comment: does this code create the new row with next-record's (eff_dt - 1) ? Also is your solution considering the Active/Inactive status ? the column `type` is the flag: `F = active` and `C = inactive`

Comment: @marie20 . . . It is considering whatever columns are in the `partition by`/`group by` lists.

Comment: i found a post which is very close to my requirement. Can this be implemented in SparkSQL somehow (instead of pyspark-sql) ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047368/split-a-row-into-two-and-dummy-some-columns

Comment: I will simplify the requirements and create a new question